# disable function chained call in elegant way

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have these two functions - basicaly one is trying to reach an element and the other is just a wrapper for the case the element was not found.In that case I dont want to allow clicking the element otherwise exception is thrown.

```
def throw_if_element_unreachable(get_element_func) -> "throws error if element is not found":
    print("in throw if element is unreachable")
    def throw(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return get_element_func(*args, **kwargs)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("in except")
            return NoSuchElementException(f"Element {args[1]} was not found!")
    return throw

@throw_if_element_unreachable
def get_clickable_element(element_path_by: 'xpath/className/id path', path: 'actual element path', driver,
                          element_index=0) -> "return the wanted element if exists":
    # check_element_in_local_storage()
    switcher = {
        ElementPathBy.CLASS_NAME: driver.find_elements_by_class_name,
        ElementPathBy.XPATH: driver.find_elements_by_xpath,
        ElementPathBy.ID: driver.find_elements_by_id
    }
    return switcher[element_path_by](path)[element_index]
```

want to prevent the .click to be called when the get_clickable_element returns None..

```
 get_clickable_element(ElementPathBy.CLASS_NAME, "buyButton", driver).click() // dont allow .click
```

what is the most elegant way to acheive this without using if..

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Does your existing code work but you want input on how to make it better or does it not work as it is?

Comment: this is not working because when the element doesnt exist the click is called on None
None.click -> throws an exception

Comment: Well, you are currently returning an exception, instead of raising one.  However, I think the bigger picture is just that you should be wrapping the call to click in a try/except block, that's what they are there for.